# TextControls in MVC 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am very new to MVC i am trying to create simple login form in **MVC 2**

This is my View:

```
<form id="LoginForm" runat="server">
    <p>
        <%=Html.TextBoxFor(Model=>Model.UserName) %>
        <%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model=>Model.UserName) %>
    <p>
</form>
```

Here it creates Textbox at runtime. So my question is how to create simple html input without use of razor ??

I have tried to use this but it does not work completely

```
<input type="text" name="<%=Html.TextBoxFor(Model=>Model.UserName) %>" 
     value="<%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model=>Model.UserName) %>" />
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to add add MVC-generated HTML inputs from the Visual Studio toolbox?

Comment: @Dai Updated my question..this should make it clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `runat="server"` in an ASP.NET MVC application. That's the first thing you should remove from your `form` tag. If you don't want to use the built-in `TextBoxFor` helper to generate an input field you could always write the markup directly:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<%= Model.UserName %>" />
```

but usually it is better to use the helpers as they will take care of things like validation and generate proper markup for you.

Comment: Thank you so much Darin...but what about the validation message ??

Comment: The validation message is generated at the server so you'd better use the built-in helper for that. There's a way to create the corresponding `<span>` tag manually but would lead to a horrible tag soup as you will have to check if there is a validation error for the corresponding field and only then generate it - things that the ValidationMessageFor helper already does for you.

Comment: The reason I am trying to use the other textbox because it is easy to format..I dont know wether we can format the built in helper textbox

Comment: Of course that you can. You could add it a class attribute: `<%=Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { @class = "someClass" }) %>` and then go ahead and define whatever formatting you want.